# Using regex to search and replace - match uppercase and lowercase - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

In a challange in freeCodeCamp - JavaScript course - Search and Replace.

The challenge is [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/search-and-replace). I tried to do regex to see if the first character in "before" and "after", but it didn`t work. So my code was:

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {

  // Check if the first character in before and after is uppercase
  // If before[0] is uppercase and after[0] is lowercase, chance after[0] to uppercase
  // If before[0] is lowercase and after[0] is uppercase, chance after[0] to lowercase

  if (before[0] === (/^[A-Z]/) && after[0] !== (/^[A-Z]/)) {
     after = after.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + after.slice(1);
   } else if (before[0] !== (/^[A-Z]/) && after[0] === (/[^A-Z]/)) {
     after = after.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + after.slice(1);
   } 

  // Replace

 str = str.replace(before, after);

  return str;
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped"); // should return "A quick brown fox leaped over the lazy dog"

myReplace("I think we should look up there", "up", "Down"); //should return "I think we should look down there"
```

I tried another way, and worked:

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {

  // Check if the first character in before and after is uppercase
  // If before[0] is uppercase and after[0] is lowercase, chance after[0] to uppercase
  // If before[0] is lowercase and after[0] is uppercase, chance after[0] to lowercase

  if (before.charAt(0) === before.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) {
    if(after.charAt(0) === after.charAt(0).toLowerCase()) {
      after = after.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + after.slice(1);
      str = str.replace(before, after)
    }
  } else {
    if(after.charAt(0) === after.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) {
      after = after.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + after.slice(1);
      str = str.replace(before, after)
    } else {
      str = str.replace(before, after)
    }
  }

  return str;
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped");
```

Comment: What do you want to reach/know exactly?

Comment: The regex was/is not the problem, more the not that structured code. Provide for every task a function, give each a name which precisely describes the task.

Comment: @KarenHirayama ... It is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex solution working

```js
function myReplace(str, before, after) {

  // Check if the first character in before and after is uppercase
  // If before[0] is uppercase and after[0] is lowercase, chance after[0] to uppercase
  // If before[0] is lowercase and after[0] is uppercase, chance after[0] to lowercase
  let pattern = "/^[A-Z]/"
  if (before[0] === (/^[A-Z]/) && after[0] !== (/^[A-Z]/)) {
     after = after.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + after.slice(1);
   } else if (!/^[A-Z]/.test(before[0]) && /^[A-Z]/.test(after[0])) {
     after = after.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + after.slice(1);
   } 

  // Replace

 str = str.replace(before, after);

  console.log(str);
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped"); // should return "A quick brown fox leaped over the lazy dog"

myReplace("I think we should look up there", "up", "Down"); //should return "I think we should look down there"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the direct comment to the OP's introduced problem ...

> *The regex was/is not the problem, more the not that structured code. Provide for every task a function, give each a name which precisely describes the task.*

The proof ...

```js
function startsWithMajuscule(str) {
  const regXStartsWith = /^[A-Z]/;

  return regXStartsWith.test(str);
}

function majusculize(str) {
  // first letter only upper case.
  return [
    str.charAt(0).toUpperCase(),
    str.substring(1),
  ].join('');
}
function minusculize(str) {
  // first letter only lower case.
  return [
    str.charAt(0).toLowerCase(),
    str.substring(1),
  ].join('');
}

function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  after = minusculize(after);

  if (startsWithMajuscule(before)) {
    after = majusculize(after);
  }
  return str.replace(before, after);
}

console.log(
  'All tests passed ?', [(
    myReplace(
      "A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.",
      "jumped",
      "leaped"
    ) === "A quick brown fox leaped over the lazy dog."
  ), (
    myReplace(
      "Let us go to the store.",
      "store",
      "mall"
    ) === "Let us go to the mall."
  ), (
    myReplace(
      "I think we should look up there.",
      "up",
      "Down"
    ) === "I think we should look down there."
  ), (
    myReplace(
      "This has a spellngi error.",
      "spellngi",
      "spelling"
    ) === "This has a spelling error."
  ), (
    myReplace(
      "His name is Tom.",
      "Tom",
      "john"
    ) === "His name is John."
  ), (
    myReplace(
      "Let us get back to more Coding.",
      "Coding",
      "algorithms"
    ) === "Let us get back to more Algorithms."
  )
].every(result => result === true))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```